# Django: unhashable type:'list' error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-2.0

I am working on Django 2 projects. I have an error that I have not encountered before. HTML Page:

```
<body>
<h1>Postlar burada görüntüleniyor</h1>
<a href="{% url 'postlar:post_olustur' %}">Post Oluştur</a>
{% for post in listelenen_postlar %}
<br>
<a href="{% url 'postlar:post_detay' post.id  %}">{{post.başlık}}</a>
<br>
{{post.içerik}}
<br>
{{post.olusturma_zamanı}}/////////////////{{post.olusturma_zamanı|timesince}} ago
<br>
{{post.güncelleme_zamanı}}
<br>   
{% endfor %}
```

Views.py

```
def post_listele(request):
 listelenen_postlar = Post.objects.all()
 context ={"listelenen_postlar":listelenen_postlar}
 return render(request,"postlar/post_listele.html",context)
```

urls.py in my app:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',view=post_listele, name="post_listele"),
url(r'^post_olustur/$',view=post_olustur, name='post_olustur'),
url(r'^post_detay/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$',view=post_detay, name='post_detay'),]
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError at /postlar/
unhashable type: 'list'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/postlar/
Django Version: 2.0.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unhashable type: 'list'
Exception Location: C:\Users\mete\Desktop\blog_deneme\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in get_order_by, line 290
Python Executable:  C:\Users\mete\Desktop\blog_deneme\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\mete\\Desktop\\blog_deneme\\blog',
 'C:\\Users\\mete\\Desktop\\blog_deneme\\venv\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\mete\\Desktop\\blog_deneme\\venv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\mete\\Desktop\\blog_deneme\\venv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\mete\\Desktop\\blog_deneme\\venv\\Scripts',
 'c:\\python\\Lib',
 'c:\\python\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\mete\\Desktop\\blog_deneme\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\mete\\Desktop\\blog_deneme\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 30 Jul 2018 22:50:33 +0000
```

Thank you..[image]

This i my model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
başlık = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=False,verbose_name="Başlık")
içerik = models.CharField(max_length=220,verbose_name="İçerik")
olusturma_zamanı = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
güncelleme_zamanı = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.başlık)
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural="Gönderilerim"
    ordering = ["id"],
```

Comment: You can't hash lists in python. You can however hash tuples instead.

Comment: `ordering = ["id"],` is the same as `ordering = (["id"],)`. You are in fact creating a tuple of lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Django is having trouble understanding how to order your queryset...

Try changing your Meta class value from:

`ordering = ["id"],`

to

`ordering = ["id",]`

Comment: thank you so much. I was working for hours but I could not find it. again thanks :)

Comment: there's a clue in the error message you sent along: ```Exception Location: C:\Users\mete\Desktop\blog_deneme\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in get_order_by``` - reading those messages very carefully can help you zero in on where your problem might be :)